How do I get Holoviz Panel Tabulator to resize it's columns and navigate to correct page when doing a DataFrame update?
I have an add_click() event and an update_click() event that handles a tabulator widget in Panel. The add_click() works perfect. When I add a new row to the DataFrame, it will resize the columns to fit the new data and navigate to the correct page where the new row is. However, the update_click() does not. I can either get the column to resize correctly, or for it to navigate to the correct page correctly. Never both at the same time. For me to get the columns to resize in update_click() I had to populate the tabulator table with an empty dataframe before updating it with the updated df because it wouldn't resize the columns for whatever reason. This however doesn't allow for the self.table.page = page_number to work. When I take out the code that populates with the empty dataframe I can get the table to navigate to the correct page, but no column resize. It's either one or the other. Any thoughts on how to achieve this?
def add_click(self, event):
        
        # update df
        name = self.add_name_txt.value.strip()
        next_id = self.df['id'].max() + 1 if not self.df.empty else 1
        new_row = pd.DataFrame({'id': [next_id], 'name': [name]})
        self.df = pd.concat([self.df, new_row], ignore_index=True)
        
        # update tabulator
        self.table.value = self.df
        
        # clear forms
        self.clear_forms()
        
        # get last index
        last_index = self.df.index[-1]
        
        # select updated row in tabulator
        self.table.selection = [last_index]
        
        # navigate to correct page in table
        page_size = self.table.page_size
        page_number = last_index // page_size + 1
        self.table.page = page_number
        
        # populate row select
        self.pop_select(last_index)
        
        # expand row select in accordion
        self.accordion.active = [0]

    def update_click(self, event):
        
        # update df
        id = int(self.update_id_lbl.value)
        name = self.update_name_txt.value.strip()
        self.df.loc[self.df['id'] == id, 'name'] = name
        
        # populate table with empty dataframe
        # workaround so that the columns will resize
        # this, however, does not allow for the 'navigate to correct page in table' to work
        empty_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=self.df.columns)
        self.table.value = empty_df
        
        # update tabulator
        self.table.value = self.df  
        
        # clear forms
        self.clear_forms()
        
        # get updated row index
        row_index = self.df[self.df['id'] == id].index[0]
        row_index = int(row_index)
        
        # select updated row in tabulator
        self.table.selection = [row_index]
        
        # navigate to correct page in table
        page_size = self.table.page_size
        page_number = row_index // page_size + 1
        self.table.page = page_number
        
        # populate row selected
        self.pop_select(row_index)
        
        # expand row select in accordion
        self.accordion.active = [0]

tried googling it to no avail, and chatgpt couldn't figure it out so now I'm here.

Found a solution Tabulator automatically resizes columns when you navigate pages so I manually navigated to first page before navigating to page where updated row is. Also, for whatever reason, it needs time to resize, so I had to add a 'time.sleep(0.01) before navigating to page_number. And that worked. Navigates to correct page, and resizes column.
